# Request for member '_file' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, pointers, struct, unions

I'm getting this error:

```
somedir/somefile.c: In function 'somefunc':
somedir/somefile.c:433:33: error: request for member '_file' in something not a 
structure or union
     ReturnValue->Val->Integer = _fileno(Param[0]->Val->Pointer);
                                 ^
```

When trying to compile next code:

```
void somefunc(struct p *P, struct Value *ReturnValue, struct Value **Param, int n)
{
    ReturnValue->Val->Integer = _fileno(Param[0]->Val->Pointer);
}
```

`ReturnValue` is a pointer to `struct Value` and there's a pointer to `union` inside which has `int Integer`

```
union SomeValue
{
    int Integer;
    void *Pointer;
}

struct Value
{
    union SomeValue *Val;
}
```

`Param` works similar too. I mean, everything seems correct because I also have another functions like this one and I haven't got any errors, only this. What's wrong? Is it related to `_fileno` function? The same thing happens when I change `_fileno` to `fileno`.

Comment: Is `Param[0]->Val->Pointer` a file?

Comment: I don't see any member named `Pointer` in the declarations you have provided.

Comment: there is no function: `_fileno`  perhaps you meant: `fileno`

Comment: @user3629249 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx

Comment: `_fileno` is MSVC function who in their wisdom deprecate `fileno`.

Comment: Or from the looks of it, MSVC in fact defines `_fileno` as a function-like *macro*.  That would explain where it gets the idea that there should be a member "`_file`" of anything, and why it puts the error location indicator where it does.

Comment: ... but that *does not* explain why MSVC is not complaining that `struct SomeValue` has no member named `Pointer`.  *That* probably arises from you cutting down your code too much.  Yes, please do limit the code you post, but also be sure to make it a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: still nothing even *close* to [mcve].

Comment: @EugeneSh, `Pointer` is declared inside `union SomeValue`.

Comment: @MotKohn Updated the post

Comment: @StepanKlymonchuk : Not in the code you have posted it is not.  You have only an `int` called `Integer`.   Whatever the member `Pointer` is it is clearly not a `FILE*` and it must be.  To understand the error you need to understand what the `_fileno` macro expands to.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks, I updated the post. How can I look at `_fileno` macro?

Comment: @StepanKlymonchuk : The macro will be defined in the header file stdio.h.  But you do not really need to; now you have corrected the code, it is clear that you have incorrect type agreement - you cannot deference a `void*`.  This no doubt is not the real code - nothing will annoy more that posting fake code for _real_ error messages - you inevitably introduce errors or omissions (as you did) such that the code posted cannot plausibly produce the error shown - causing an unnecessary comment storm.  If this _is_ real code you really need to reconsider your symbol-naming convention.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks anyway, I'll consider that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_filno` appears in this case to be defined as a macro; when the macro is expanded, there is an attempt to dereference the pointer argument and access the `_file` member for example `arg->_file`.  However this will fail because you cannot deference a `void*`.

Pointer should either be of type `FILE*` or be assigned from a valid `FILE*` object and then cast when passed to `_fileno()`:

```
ReturnValue->Val->Integer = _fileno( (FILE*)Param[0]->Val->Pointer ) ;
```